# Cannot load new SpriteKit SKScene with touch of the button

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uitouch

I can not load the new scene with touch of the button on the scene. 
Button named: BuStartGame 
Scene to load: CategoriesScene 
Scene to load class: CategoriesSceneClass.

Here is my code.

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import UIKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event:UIEvent?){
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self);

            //Mark: ===================== StartGame
            if atPoint(location).name == "BuStartGame"{
                if let scene = CategoriesSceneClass(fileNamed:"CategoriesScene"){
                    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                    view!.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.doorsOpenVertical(withDuration: 2))

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDITED:
I see that the problem is in this code. When I delete IF it works, but as a button work the whole scene.

```
if atPoint(location).name == "BuStartGame"{
```

Comment: If you step through your code, does it get to the call to `presentScene`?

Comment: Looks weird, but yes. I have got another buttons on the scene. There are some times rendered on the simulator, and sometimes not...

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with a demo game in SpriteKit last year, here is some code I used for a similar button transition, changed class name and file name to yours below. Try replacing this in your "if let scene" section.

```
if let scene = CategoriesSceneClass(fileNamed:"CategoriesScene") {

            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view!
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true


            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
          skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = false 


            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            skView.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.doorsOpenVertical(withDuration: 2))
```

Comment: Unfortunetely it do not work. I see that the problem is in this code. When I delete IF it works, but as a button work the whole scene. 
if atPoint(location).name == "BuStartGame"{

Answer (score 0):

This code solved problem

```
  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {  
        for touch in touches {   
            let location = touch.location(in: self);  
            if atPoint(location).name == "Start" {   
                    print("I'm at start point")  
                if let view = self.view {  
                    print("gonna create scene")  
                    if let scene = GameplaySceneClass(fileNamed: "GameplayScene") {  
                        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill  
                        print("prepare to transition")  
                        view.presentScene(scene,transition:  
                                SKTransition.doorsOpenVertical(withDuration:  
                                TimeInterval(2)));  
                    }  
            }  
        }  
    }
```